# iOS UI design - what dimension size Sketch file to give to developer?

Tags: interface-design, sketch-app, ios

Assuming an iOS app has been designed for iphone 4,5,6,6+ and iPad, what is the ideal dimension Sketch file to give to a developer? This is also assuming there are no major layout changes in the actual design.

I'm basically just wanting to avoid having to create a separate version for each resolution. Is it fair to just give 1 canvas size of the app and have the developer do the rest? I've been told by a previous colleague to just give 640x1136 and let him do the rest, but would like some other opinions.

Comment: The only answer to this is: ask your developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://screensiz.es/phone is a nice resource.

I'm not sure how your team is structured, but for us it's all up to the Product Owner.  He determines for us if it's important to provide exact specs for all phone sizes, or if it's OK to leave it up to the frameworks/tools the developers have to handle the appropriate size of elements, typography, etc.

I'd go to your devs, PO, PM, etc and present your question so everyone can get on the same page.

Comment: Hey Aaron! Welcome to GD.SE! If you have any questions about the site have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to hit one of us up in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. See ya around! :)